# How to get every page of playlists from Spotify API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, spotify

I'm trying to get all of a user's playlists from the spotify API and put them in a selecting list. I can only access 20 playlists at a time so I created a while loop that uses the next-page property to go through every page of playlists, but for some reason it results in an infinite loop. I'm guessing that the issue is in the uri = playlist.next line, as highlighted below. Any help would be really appreciated, here's the code:

```
        //Request the user's information...
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            //... Create a list of the user's playlists
            success: function(user) {
              var playlistURL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user.id + '/playlists';

              appendPlaylists(playlistURL);

              function appendPlaylists(nextURL) {
                if (nextURL == null) {
                  return;
                }
                //Append playlists to the menu
                $.ajax({
                    url: nextURL,
                    headers: {
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                    },
                    success: function(playlists) {
                      console.log(nextURL);

                      var i = 0;
                      while (playlists.items[i] != null) {
                        console.log(playlists.items[i].name);
                        $('.all-playlists').append('<option value="' + playlists.items[i].href + '">' + playlists.items[i].name + '</option>')
                        i++;
                      }
                      appendPlaylists(playlists.next);
                    }    
                });
              }

              //Load the logged in div.
              $('#login').hide();
              $('#loggedin').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: you're getting the first page twice.

Comment: You're right, I thought I had a really good reason for doing that, but it turns out I had just overthought the problem. Thanks. I'll update the code.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are considering the ajax requests to be blocking, when they are asynchronous. Instead of having he request in you infinite loop, make the request to the next chunk in the success callback of your previous request. Create a function that makes a request accepting an offset (or the 'next' URLs and then inside that function, when the request has succeeded, call itself with the URL of the next chunk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't know about blocking and asynchronous requests. Would this be classified as recursion? It seems very close to it. I'll update the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [JMPerez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540274/jmperez) for the answer:

> I think the problem is that you are considering the ajax requests to be blocking, when they are asynchronous. Instead of having he request in you infinite loop, make the request to the next chunk in the success callback of your previous request. Create a function that makes a request accepting an offset (or the 'next' URLs and then inside that function, when the request has succeeded, call itself with the URL of the next chunk.

The updated code  has been added to the question above.